# java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple sources found for jdbc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to load data into hive able while loading data into hive table i'm experiencing error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple sources found for jdbc" any help will be appreciable.

```
val url1="jdbc:hive2://xxxxxx.google.com:10000/jkl_cak_coh_batch;principal=hive/xxxxxx.google.com@internal.lllglobal.com;mapred.job.queue.name=io9;AuthMech=3;SSL=1;" +
          "SSLTrustStore=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/security/oooacerts;user=xxxx;password=yyyyy"


val connectionProperties = new Properties()
        connectionProperties.put("user", "xxxxxx")
        connectionProperties.put("password", "xxxxxx")

   sparkSession.sqlContext.sql("select * from " + tmpTable )
    .write
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append) // <--- Append in existing table
    .option("driver", driverName)
    .option("header","false")
    .jdbc(url1, "sourceTable", connectionProperties)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple sources found for jdbc (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource), please specify the fully qualified class name.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:591)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:446)
        at com.rxxxrp.opanada_launus.LoadData.loadDFToDB(LoadData.scala:140)
        at com.rxxxrp.opanada_launus.jkanadaTaunus$.main(Tanadaaunus.scala:139)
        at com.rxxxrp.jkanada_tllunus.opanadalaunus.main(Tanadaaunus.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource")
```

It is not only unnecessary (you use `jdbc` method) and incorrect (doesn't specify the specific implementation)

In general if you want to use `format` option just

```
.format("jdbc")
```

Comment: @user9318576 , did you found any solution for the same ? 
As there is a similar issue found - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151363/not-able-to-write-spark-dataset-to-database-using-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly suggest that your cluster have two different class that uses jdbc format. So when you are specifying the json you need to provide the fully qualified class name so code knows which class to utilize.

You can use one of the class as per your need.

```
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider")
```

or

```
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource")
```

if you use just the jdbc it cannot identify which class it should use and is throwing the error that you see.